# Should I fill a dropdown list with YES/NO options from a database or do it directly with HTML?

Tags: html, database, web

What's the best way to fill a dropdown list with YES/NO options?

Do it directly into the HTML code like this?:

```
<select class="form-control">
  <option>Select your answer</option>
  <option>Yes</option>
  <option>No</option>
</select>
```

Or do it with a table from a database and insert it into html like this?:

```
@Html.DropDownList("cmbQuestion", binaryAnswer, "Select your answer", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Edit: If I know the dropdownlist options probably won't change.

Comment: Honestly, whichever one is less work for you.

Comment: It's worth noting you could also have a list in your codebehind if you're using something like .NET which has these (Y/N) options & then binds to the `<select>`, which means it is theoretically hardcoded, but much easier to propogate data if you use some sort of repeater.

Comment: There's no "right" answer to this.

Comment: It also depends on how much code repetition there's going to be! If you're going to do Y/N 50+ times, maybe hardcoded in HTML isn't the way to go

Comment: Why use a select box for this?  Why not a checkbox or a radio button?

Comment: opinion: use the hardcoding for something simple like this, do it in HTML

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that the data will *never* change (= you can't), feel free to hardcode it. But experience shows that data *will* change over time and you will make it easier for you if you make the code do the data display programmatically. It's also "cleaner", because it separates concerns to some degree, namely data and presentation.

Comment: Have you heard of the YAGNI principle?